# Automatically adjust audio volume levels

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer, audio-normalization

When I am listening to music with Windows Media Player, I would like all songs to be around the same volume level. That's why I tried the automatic volume leveling, but when activated, it always says that it is not available for the current media. Am I doing something wrong? Are there good alternatives? I tried to use the enhancement in the speaker settings, but my speaker does not have the enhancement tab showing up.

[image]

I also tried Mp3Gain to normalize volume levels, which worked - however, I found out that in some cases, the new audio level caused some high pitch parts of the mp3 to sound harsh, which otherwise (with original levels) wouldn't. So that's not an option anymore.

Comment: Does this post answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/286061/normalize-volume-of-all-my-computer-hardware-and-software

Comment: You might try Eqaulizer APO, https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ , though I have not tested it.

Comment: @harrymc Theoretically yes, but unfortunately the suggested solution (Loudness Equalization) is not available for my dpeakerd

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik OK, but how would that work? From what I understand you can create your oen filters?

Comment: Re: Equalization, it is not *normalization*, but application of the Fletcher-Munson curve, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour. As for the app, I've not tried it, but it seems to have normalization with attack and decay time settings.